# Finding all instances of a value using structured references

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016, excel-tables

in Excel 2016, I am trying to print the names of those who scored the highest on a test using structured references to refer to the table of data. It is possible for multiple people to have the same number of points, so I want to set it up to show all of the names that earned the score specified in cell $K$5.

It works perfectly with named ranges:

```
INDEX(Name), SMALL(IF($K$5=Total,ROW(Name)-3,""),ROW()-5))
```

But I'm trying to put all of the information into a defined table so it's easier to sort and adjust, and I cannot get it to work with structured references.  This is what I have so far, and it returns a #VALUE error.

```
INDEX(tblScores[NAME], SMALL(IF($K$5=tblScores[TOTAL],ROW(tblScores[NAME])-3,""),ROW()-5))
```

Comment: one of two or both: either `ROW(tblScores[NAME])-3` returns a negative number or `ROW()-5` is less than or equal to `0`.  On the prior use: `ROW(tblScores[NAME]) - MIN(ROW(tblScores[NAME]))+1` on the later use `ROW(ZZ1)`  Do not rely on hardcoded corrections to the rows, as they may be wrong depending on where the data or formula are placed.

Comment: And make sure to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.